# Using x-forwarded-for to fetch google search

Tags: php

I am creating a proxy that compresses data fetched from website before serving to user  "browser". Everything works fine except google search. The problem is that even though I transfer IP address of user via `X-FORWARDED-FOR`, yet I get results based on US (where my servers are located).

I am using PHP curl to fetch pages and have tried setting `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` with `X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `X-FORWARDED-FOR`, `REMOTE_ADDR` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` with user's IP address, but none helped.

Any idea now how to convince google that my location is e.g. Japan not US where my servers are located.

**Edit:** There is a solution using iframe, but that's not the solution that I am looking for. How does any other service which compress website data before delivering solve this problem.

Comment: What about using an iframe for the Google search part of the site?

Comment: I want to server page as it normally would have. I see UC Browser doing it.

Comment: You should be able to style the iframe into the page nicely and only the very curious will find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem by using user country to find google's country specific search domain and direct the traffic to that domain.

Here is 
[List of google search domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains)